# file upload in FileNet?

Tags: java, file-upload, filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

I'm writing code to upload a file in FileNet.
A standalone java program to take the some inputs, and upload it in FileNet. I'm new to FileNet. Can you help me out, How to do it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Document.java` provided by IBM for your activities and many other Java classes

```
package fbis.apitocasemanager;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.user.DocumentUtil;

public class Addfilescasemanager {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void addfiles_toicm(String directory, String lFolderPath)
    {
        try {
        DocumentUtil.initialize();
        String path = directory;
        System.out.println("This is the path:..............................."
                + path);
        String file_name;
        File folder = new File(directory);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
        {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile())
            {
                file_name = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                System.out.println(file_name);
                String filePaths = directory + file_name;
                // File file = new File("C:\\FNB\\att.jpg");
                File file = new File(filePaths);
                InputStream attStream = null;
                    attStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                DocumentUtil.addDocumentWithStream(lFolderPath, attStream,
                        "image/jpeg", file_name, "Document");
            }
        }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }//end of method

    public static void addfile_toicm(File file_name, String lFolderPath)
    {
        try {
        DocumentUtil.initialize();
                InputStream attStream = null;
                    attStream = new FileInputStream(file_name);
                DocumentUtil.addDocumentWithStream(lFolderPath, attStream,
                        "image/jpeg", file_name.getName(), "Document");
                System.out.println("File added successfully");
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
    }//end of method
    public static void main(String nag[])
    {
        addfiles_toicm("E:\\FSPATH1\\BLR_14122012_001F1A\\","/IBM Case Manager/Solution Deployments/Surakshate Solution for form 2/Case Types/FISB_FactoriesRegistration/Cases/2012/12/06/16/000000100103");
    }
}
```

and my `DocumentUtil` class is

```
package com.user;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.security.auth.Subject;

import com.filenet.api.collection.ContentElementList;
import com.filenet.api.constants.AutoClassify;
import com.filenet.api.constants.AutoUniqueName;
import com.filenet.api.constants.CheckinType;
import com.filenet.api.constants.DefineSecurityParentage;
import com.filenet.api.constants.RefreshMode;
import com.filenet.api.core.Connection;
import com.filenet.api.core.ContentTransfer;
import com.filenet.api.core.Document;
import com.filenet.api.core.Domain;
import com.filenet.api.core.Factory;
import com.filenet.api.core.Folder;
import com.filenet.api.core.ObjectStore;
import com.filenet.api.core.ReferentialContainmentRelationship;
import com.filenet.api.util.UserContext;

public class DocumentUtil {

    public static ObjectStore objectStore = null;

    public static Domain domain = null;
    public static Connection connection = null;


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        initialize();
        /*
        addDocumentWithPath("/FNB", "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Sample.txt.txt",
                "text/plain", "NNN", "Document");
        */
        File file = new File("E:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\TT.txt");

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        addDocumentWithStream("/FNB", fis, "text/plain", "My New Doc", "Document");
    }

    public static void initialize()
    {

        System.setProperty("WASP.LOCATION", "C:\\Progra~1\\IBM\\WebSphere\\AppServer\\profiles\\AppSrv01\\installedApps\\P8Node01Cell\\FileNetEngine.ear \\cews.war\\WEB-INF\\classes\\com\\filenet\\engine\\wsi");
        System.setProperty("SECURITY.AUTH.LOGIN.CONFIG",
                "C:\\Progra~1\\IBM\\WebSphere\\AppServer\\profiles\\AppSrv01\\installedApps\\P8Node01Cell\\FileNetEngine.ear\\client-download.war\\FileNet\\Download\\dap501.153\\jaas.conf.wsi");
        System.setProperty(":SECURITY.AUTH.LOGIN.CONFIG",
                "C:\\Progra~1\\IBM\\WebSphere\\AppServer\\profiles\\AppSrv01\\installedApps\\P8Node01Cell\\FileNetEngine.ear\\client-download.war\\FileNet\\Download\\dap501.153\\jaas.conf.wsi");
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config","C:\\Progra~1\\IBM\\WebSphere\\AppServer\\java\\jre");
        connection = Factory.Connection.getConnection(CEConnection.uri);
        Subject sub = UserContext.createSubject(connection,
                com.user.CEConnection.username, CEConnection.password,
                CEConnection.stanza);
        UserContext.get().pushSubject(sub);
        domain = Factory.Domain.getInstance(connection, null);
        objectStore = Factory.ObjectStore.fetchInstance(domain, "TARGET", null);
        System.out.println("\n\n objectStore--> " + objectStore.get_DisplayName());
    }

    public static void addDocumentWithPath(String folderPath, String filePath,
            String mimeType, String docName, String docClass) {

        Folder folder = Factory.Folder.fetchInstance(objectStore,
                folderPath, null);

        System.out.println("\n\n Folder ID: " + folder.get_Id());
        // Document doc = Factory.Document.createInstance(os, classId);

        Document doc = CEUtil.createDocWithContent(new File(filePath), mimeType, 
                objectStore, docName, docClass);

        doc.save(RefreshMode.REFRESH);

        doc = CEUtil.createDocNoContent(mimeType, objectStore, docName, docClass);
        doc.save(RefreshMode.REFRESH);
        CEUtil.checkinDoc(doc);
        ReferentialContainmentRelationship rcr = CEUtil.fileObject(objectStore, doc, folderPath);
        rcr.save(RefreshMode.REFRESH);

    }

    public static void addDocumentWithStream(String folderPath,
            InputStream inputStream, String mimeType, 
            String docName, String docClass) {

        Folder folder = Factory.Folder.fetchInstance(objectStore,
                folderPath, null);

        System.out.println("\n\n Folder ID: " + folder.get_Id());
        // Document doc = Factory.Document.createInstance(os, classId);

        Document doc = Factory.Document.createInstance(objectStore, null);

        ContentElementList contEleList = Factory.ContentElement.createList();
        ContentTransfer ct = Factory.ContentTransfer.createInstance();

        ct.setCaptureSource(inputStream);
        ct.set_ContentType(mimeType);
        ct.set_RetrievalName(docName);
        contEleList.add(ct);

        doc.set_ContentElements(contEleList);
        doc.getProperties().putValue("DocumentTitle", docName);

        doc.set_MimeType(mimeType);
        doc.checkin(AutoClassify.AUTO_CLASSIFY, CheckinType.MAJOR_VERSION);
        doc.save(RefreshMode.REFRESH);

        ReferentialContainmentRelationship rcr = folder.file(doc,
                AutoUniqueName.AUTO_UNIQUE, docName, 
                DefineSecurityParentage.DO_NOT_DEFINE_SECURITY_PARENTAGE);
        rcr.save(RefreshMode.REFRESH);
        /*

        doc.save(RefreshMode.REFRESH);

        doc = CEUtil.createDocNoContent(mimeType, objectStore, docName, docClass);

        CEUtil.checkinDoc(doc);
        ReferentialContainmentRelationship rcr = CEUtil.fileObject(objectStore, doc, folderPath);
        rcr.save(RefreshMode.REFRESH);
        */
    }

    public static ObjectStore getObjecctStore()
    {
        if (objectStore != null) {
            return objectStore;
        }

        // Make connection.
        com.filenet.api.core.Connection conn = Factory.Connection
                .getConnection(CEConnection.uri);
        Subject subject = UserContext.createSubject(conn,
                CEConnection.username, CEConnection.password, null);
        UserContext.get().pushSubject(subject);

        try {
            // Get default domain.
            Domain domain = Factory.Domain.getInstance(conn, null);


            // Get object stores for domain.
            objectStore = Factory.ObjectStore.fetchInstance(domain, "TARGET",
                    null);

            System.out.println("\n\n Connection to Content Engine successful !!");
        } finally {
            UserContext.get().popSubject();
        }

        return objectStore;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is extremely good. Just wanted to save people some time but I don't have the points to comment so am adding this as an answer.

Eclipse wasted a lot of my time getting the above to work because it suggested the wrong classes to import. Here's the list of correct ones:

```
import com.filenet.api.collection.ContentElementList;
import com.filenet.api.constants.AutoClassify;
import com.filenet.api.constants.AutoUniqueName;
import com.filenet.api.constants.CheckinType;
import com.filenet.api.constants.DefineSecurityParentage;
import com.filenet.api.constants.RefreshMode;
import com.filenet.api.core.Document;
import com.filenet.api.core.ObjectStore;
import com.filenet.api.core.ContentTransfer;
import com.filenet.api.core.Folder;
import com.filenet.api.core.Factory;
import com.filenet.api.core.ReferentialContainmentRelationship;
```